# What is the difference between background, backgroundTint, backgroundTintMode attributes in android layout xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

While working with the android layout xml I came across `backgroundTint` attribute . I don't understand what  is for.

Also what is `backgroundTintMode` ??

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I tested various combinations of `android:background`, `android:backgroundTint` and `android:backgroundTintMode`.

`android:backgroundTint` applies the color filter to the resource of `android:background` when used together with `android:backgroundTintMode`.

Here are the results:

[image: Tint Check]

Here's the code if you want to experiment further:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:background="#37AEE4"
        android:text="Background" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FEFBDE"
        android:text="Background tint" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:background="#37AEE4"
        android:backgroundTint="#FEFBDE"
        android:text="Both together" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:background="#37AEE4"
        android:backgroundTint="#FEFBDE"
        android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        android:text="With tint mode" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:text="Without any" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your second TextView example, I wonder when using only `android:backgroundTint` without `android:background`, this second TextView doesn't change anything. However, I try `android:backgroundTint` in Button, the color of button look like the same color of backgroundTint that I set. Could you explain these cases?

Comment: @VinhNguyen, `android:background` property must be set for the `android:backgroundTint` to be visible on `TextView`. In case of the `Button`, I'm guessing that it already has some sort of background/color set by the framework.

Answer (score 23):

I won't stress much on the difference as it is already covered, but notice the below:

- `android:backgroundTint` `android:backgroundTintMode` are only available at API 21
- If you have a widget that has a png/vector drawable background set by `android:background`, and you want to change its default color, then you can use `android:backgroundTint` to add a shade to it.

**example**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

[image]

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />
```

[image]

**Another example**

If you try to change the accent color of the `FloatingActionButton` using `android:background` you won't notice a change, that is because it's already utilizes `app:srcCompat`, so in order to do that you can use `android:backgroundTint` instead

Answer (score 17):

The `backgroundTint` attribute will help you to add a tint(shade) to the background. You can provide a color value for the same in the form of - `"#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".`

The `backgroundTintMode` on the other hand will help you to apply the background tint. It must have constant values like `src_over, src_in, src_atop,` etc.

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:backgroundTintMode) to get a clear idea of the the constant values that can be used. Search for the `backgroundTint` attribute and the description along with various attributes will be available.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: No, it's not. Can you check again?

Answer (score 4):

BackgroundTint works as color filter.

## FEFBDE as tint

## 37AEE4 as background

Try seeing the difference by comment tint/background and check the output when both are set.

Answer (score 4):

[**android:backgroundTintMode**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:backgroundTintMode)

> Blending mode used to apply the background tint.

[**android:backgroundTint**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:backgroundTint)

> Tint to apply to the background. Must be a color value, in the form of `#rgb`, `#argb`, `#rrggbb`, or `#aarrggbb`.
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
> "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
> "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.