# Android FloatingActionButton suddenly is transparent only on ProGuard build

Tags: android, android-appcompat, floating-action-button

After updating my AppCompat library to 25 when I build release with proguard all of my FloatingActionButton backgrounds are transparent. When i build a debug build without proguard it is colored like it should be.

Layout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_upload"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/content_frame"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_fab_upload"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/big_padding"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_social"/>
```

Gradle

```
compileSdkVersion = 25
buildToolsVersion = '25.0.0'
supportLibVersion = '25.0.0'

supportLibAppCompat = "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
supportLibCardView = "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
supportLibRecyclerView = "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
supportLibDesign = "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
supportLibPalette = "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibVersion"
supportLibPercent = "com.android.support:percent:$supportLibVersion"
```

I don't have any references to AppCompat in my proguard config.

**UPDATE**

I just tried another one of my projects and it has the same issue. The issue seems to stem from updating Android Studio to 2.3 Canary build.

Comment: check your color file and set the color accent if it is transparent

Comment: No it is as it should be <color name="fab_social">#19c4d8</color>

Answer (score 4):

I have found and fixed the issue.

As stated in my update above the issue started when I updated to Android Studio 2.3 Canary. When doing that is updated my android build tools to 2.3 alhpa. I changed it back to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`

and now the fab is as it should be.

To clarify I am still on Android Studio 2.3 Canary, I just did not update the android build tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `backgroundTint` to `background`here is an example which show the difference between background tint and background [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471009/what-is-the-difference-between-background-backgroundtint-backgroundtintmode-at).

So your code will be

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab_upload"
android:visibility="gone"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
app:layout_anchor="@id/content_frame"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
android:src="@drawable/app_fab_upload"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/big_padding"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@color/fab_social"/>
```