# How to wrap each line of TextView with background?

Tags: android, textview

I have TextView which contains text. It has background:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!\nEach line should be wrapped by background not whole text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
```

Now, a background is wrapping whole text. I want it to wrap each line individually. Now I am getting the result which is shown on the left of the image. I want to achieve the result which is on the right.

[image]

I would create several TextViews with separate backgrounds but TextView shows dynamic text which makes this solution not so good.

My question: how to wrap TextView's each line with background?

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080463/3395198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SpannableString`

```
 SpannableString str = new SpannableString("Highlighted. Not highlighted.");
 str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), 0, 11, 0);
 textView.setText(str);
```

if you want the entire string to highlight

```
 str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), 0, str.length(), 0);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Now I will try this solution)

Comment: sure it will help you.)