# Picasso loading black images from URL

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, picasso

The layout of my activity is like this:

There is a view pager:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
    >

    <VerticalViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The column layout for each entry in viewpager is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Default category"
    android:id="@+id/name"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And each item of the recyclerview has the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:tint="@android:color/black"
            android:padding="5dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In onBindViewHolder I am using this code:

```
Uri img_uri = Uri.parse(img_url);

    final String TAG = "loadImgUrl";
    Log.d(TAG, "Loading image from url: " + img_url);



    try {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .setLoggingEnabled(true);

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(img_uri)
                .resize(250,250)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.call)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.event)
                .into(imageView);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        iae.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the result is always a black image. The same code works If I use a drawable stored in the app.

There is no error in picasso log or the app log. I have tried using into(Target) as well but same problem occurs and the error callbacks are never called.

Anyone has any idea why this is so?

Comment: May I please know the reason why someone downvoted this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are adding a black to the tint to the image view in which you are showing images.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:tint="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="5dp" />
```

just remove the tint `android:tint="@android:color/black"`

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />
```

read [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471009/what-is-the-difference-between-background-backgroundtint-backgroundtintmode-at) about tint here and when to use

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a silly mistake. I have been spending hours on it.

Comment: it's okay Daniyal we programmers do mistakes occasionally and this is why we are here to help each other on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

problem with this line  android:tint="@android:color/black", when you are apply this, image is getting black and your image is not displaying.