# Can't change background color on MaterialButton without change colorAccent

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

Android Studio 3.2.1
Here my layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/bittrexJsonViewButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                android:text="@string/json_view"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton" />
```

to change **MaterialButton's** background I change **colorAccent** in **styles.xml**

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Nice. It's work.

But the problem is: I do not want to change **colorAccent**. I want to use background's color for **MaterialButton's** different from **colorAccent**

Attribute:

```
android:background="#aabbcc"
```

not help.

Answer (score 82):

**1st Solution**

You can use `app:backgroundTint` to change back ground color of `MaterialButton`

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/bittrexJsonViewButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:text="@string/json_view"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton" />
```

**2nd Solution**

`MaterialButton` uses `colorPrimary` as background when button is in active state and `colorOnSurface` when disabled. So, you can define it in your theme and apply it on material buttons

Comment: I can't use app:backgroundTint because minSdkVersion 18

Comment: try 2nd solution

Comment: I have tried it with min version 18. There is no issue. I think you are not using androidX. If you want to use new material components then I recommend to migrate your project to AndroidX

Comment: I migrate to AndroidX. If you run application on Android 5.0 then button not change background color. In this case app:backgroundTint - not help.

Comment: Yeah you have to use AppCompat Theme on Lolipop and Pre Lolipop version, AFIK

Comment: app:backgroundTint  its working on 5.0 . I just tested it on LG having version 5.0

Comment: colorOnSurface is not working for me for some reason :(

Comment: @ZaidMirza i just tested with v19 and backgroundTint is not working for me also i have migrated to android X

Comment: it will override colors for all states, disabled button will be the same as enabled button. very bad answer

Answer (score 53):

With the [`MaterialButton`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) you have 2 options:

1. Using the `backgroundTint` attribute as suggest by [Zaid Mirza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088415/2016562)
2. If you want to override some theme attributes from a default style you can use new **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute. It is the best option in my opinion.

Something like:

```
<style name="Widget.App.ButtonStyle"
 parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
   <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/GreenButtonThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="GreenButtonThemeOverlay">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

and then:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   style="Widget.App.ButtonStyle"
   ../>
```

It requires at least the version **1.1.0** of the library.

Comment: It requires material 1.1.0, which is inexistent as shown [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material)

Comment: @DarioColetto But the solution works. The theme and the style from which you can derive your style for buttons exist. I have tried it just now.

Comment: Well, the answer is from 2019, my comment too, the problem was that material 1.1.0 wasn't released as stable yet... Now it is available, of course :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's something that in my opinion we all should know how to do. Creating a style, extending from a parent style, and changing nothing but only one attribute. Thank you

Answer (score 44):

If you want to set custom drawable you need to make the `app:backgroundTint="@null"`. For just changing the background colour `app:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"`

I'm currently using `1.3.0-alpha01`

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/bittrexJsonViewButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_default_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_default_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/your_custom_drawable"
            android:text="@string/json_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton" />
```

Comment: It works, but It showed the error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to get ShapeAppearanceModel from a MaterialButton which has an overwritten background." when tried to inflate `MaterialButton` from `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it by following the below code.

```
                android:background="@color/black"
                app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

Answer (score 5):

2020: It seems that they just fixed this on April 1st 2020.

It should be released on 1.2.0 beta 1 since the [GitHub issue was closed as 
"Fixed"](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/889)

Answer (score 3):

`backgroundTint` also changed the disabled state color so wasn't good for me

Best solution i could find was to override the primary color for the `MaterialButton` (only) through overlay style

Add this code to your styles.

Replace `?attr/colorSecondary` to whatever color you want

```
<style name="MyButtonTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ButtonStyleTextColor</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonStyleTextColor">
    <item name="colorPrimary">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Add the theme to the button

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
//..
android:theme="@style/MyButtonTheme"/>
```

### Or

If you  you using [MDC](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-kotlin#0) and you want to change the theme for all buttons:

Add this row to your themes.xml

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Button.MyTheme</item>
```

and add these lines to your type.xml

```
<style name="Button.MyTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ButtonStyleTextColor</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonStyleTextColor">
    <item name="colorPrimary">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

In that case you don't need to add `android:theme="@style/MyButtonTheme"` to your `MaterialButton`

If any mistake please let me know and don't be hurry to downgrade

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is described below:

On Button tag

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/login_btn"
     style="@style/PrimaryButtonStyle"
     app:backgroundTint="@null"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:text="@string/txtBtnLogin" />
```

@Style/PrimaryButtonStyle

```
<style name="PrimaryButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/base_button_style</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

[image: Output]

Output of this - Button background (light blue) is different than layout background (Comparatively dark blue)

Answer (score 1):

**BackgroundTint** Always works on material buttons, but first, do uninstall the app and reinstall it again. Sometimes changes may not reflect until you reinstall the app.

`android:backgroundTint` is applied over the `android:background` and
their combination can be controlled by `android:backgroundTintMode`

do check this answer for difference between `android:background`, `android:backgroundTint` and `android:backgroundTintMode`

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080463/14289342**

Answer (score 0):

Change the `backgroundTintMode` to `add` and then your `background` attribute will be displayed. See example below:

```html
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/bittrexJsonViewButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                android:text="@string/json_view"
                android:background:"#aabbcc"
                app:backgroundTintMode="add"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/binanceJsonViewButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments asking about disable color using colorOnSurface you need to use theme settings,

Like this:

```
<style name="MaterialRedButton"
    parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MaterialRedButtonThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialRedButtonThemeOverlay">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and here is what it did:
create a new style with a parent of a style of on of the material button styles and change the background color and background tint in it.. hopefully it will work with you..

```xml
<style name="DialogMaterialButtonOkay" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.UnelevatedButton">
        <item name="background">@color/button_background_color_main</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_background_color_main</item>  
</style>
```