# MaterialButton with custom stroke

Tags: android, button, material-components-android

I'm trying to create a button with the following look in android studio.

[image]

The theme I use is `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` and I understood (maybe not correctly) that the default theme to use now days is "Material".

From what I see, it is not possible to create the border from the button properties itself.
I found [the following example](https://www.android-examples.com/add-dash-dotted-border-around-to-button-in-android/) to create a shape with the dashes I want.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:dashWidth="12dp"
                android:color="@color/light_green"
                android:dashGap="5dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then, I tried to attach it to my button using `android:background="@drawable/dash_border"`. This added the border to my button but my button still had a "green" background. Then, I found out `MaterialButton` uses the `PrimaryColor` as the background and to override it you need to specify the button it's own theme. [See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087014/cant-change-background-color-on-materialbutton-without-change-coloraccent).

```
    <style name="EmptyButtonTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/EmptyButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EmptyButtonStyle">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

And then adding `android:theme="@style/EmptyButtonTheme"` to my button.
Now final result I got into is:
[image]

which is not the green button I wanted.

Notice that `light_green` is `<color name="light_green">#9DC88D</color>`

How can I get to the desired result in the easiest way?
I might have used `MaterialButton` in an over-kill way.

Notice that the same result happen with `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` and `Button` as my button type.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328270/android-button-background-is-taking-the-primary-color) question but it use the default button properties which doesn't work in my case.

Comment: And the solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328270/android-button-background-is-taking-the-primary-color/63331089#63331089. `Button` and `MaterialButton` are the same with a `MaterialComponents` Theme. To avoid that the custom background doesn't get tinted with the `attr/colorPrimary` defined in your theme. you have to add `app:backgroundTint="@null"`to your `MaterialButton`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style name="Button.MyTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
     
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/dash_border</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_16</item>
    </style>
```

Apply this Style directly to your button

Comment: I has the green background which was specified by my PrimaryColor

Comment: have you applied the style ?

Comment: yes. do you have a small example which you can share?

Comment: @MyNick you have to apply this with `style="Button.MyTheme"` and not with `android:theme="@style/EmptyButtonTheme"`

Comment: you can accept the answer then