# How to implement a circular xml in main activity android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-resources

I am working on creating a traffic light application. its very simple just a TextView and button. I wanted the TextView to be circular so I created a recourse file in drawable called circular and set it as the label background.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/traffic_light_label"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

The label does change from a square a circle shape in the xml file. but when I try changing the background color in the main activity the shape reverts back to square I tried calling the drawable object in the main activity as well but it did not work. any suggestion on what I should do.

Main activity file: this is what causes the shape to revert back to square

```
        light=findViewById(R.id.traffic_light_label);
        light.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

circular recourse file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <size android:width="100dp"
          android:height="100dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: can you update your question and add to it the "@drawable/circular" code

Comment: I updated the question and added the @drawable/circular file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your drawable file to be like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

After doing that and adding it to your `TextView` as background, you can edit your java file also and add this:

```
TextView light = findViewById(R.id.traffic_light_label);
light.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You Don't need to gives background color to that view because you already gave a background in the xml file.

If you need to change only color of a background then you just need to add background Tint property on that view.

Refer this Answer for more specific details on background and background tint just for your knowledge.

> [What is the difference between background, backgroundTint, backgroundTintMode attributes in android layout xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471009/what-is-the-difference-between-background-backgroundtint-backgroundtintmode-at)

```
   textView.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#57B92F"))
```

Use this code on your view it works fine in my case.